Cannot Access Express Route: "cannot GET /" Error
I'm trying to set up a simple Express.js server to respond with "Hello World" at the root endpoint (/). However, when I run my server and access http://localhost:3000/, I get a "cannot GET /" error in the browser. The terminal shows the message Server running on 3000, but it doesn't return the expected response.Is there something I might be missing, or is there a specific reason why my Express route isn't working as expected?My code Local host
I made sure the code was saved before running the server. I stopped the current server by ctrl+c and started again by using node index.js. Despite this, I still receive the "cannot GET /" error.

Have you tried like this?
const express = require('express');


The problem is with the first line of your script:
import express from "express";

If you want this to work without errors, you need to add this to your package.json:
...
"type": "module",
...

Alternatively, you can also replace import express from "express"; by const express = require('express');
In this case, you don't need to modify your package.json
